# Loading progress bar like Telegram

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I want loading process exactly like this :

[image]

I try this :

```
    <style name="CustomProgress" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

and

```
pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext(), R.style.CustomProgress);
```

but this is not exactly that i want!

Comment: there are lots of third party library thats provide you such a cool progress bar try this one: https://github.com/ybq/Android-SpinKit

Comment: thank you , but i dont want use library. i want use style and CustomProgress.

Comment: you can try to customs circle progress bar to match what you need. at lease, try it one

Answer (score 0):

Create circle drawable `progress_background.xml`

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
<solid android:color="#BC000000" />
```

You can directly use the background on progress Bar itself . You can also do it with `style`.

```
 <ProgressBar
            android:indeterminateTint="@android:color/white"
            android:indeterminateTintMode="src_in"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/progress"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

`android:indeterminateTint` is available on 21+. If your minimum SDK version is lower then it then you can change progress bar color with other way but you get the idea.